# Would a runtime of (n choose (n/2)) be considered polynomial?

Tags: np-complete

Simple question, given an input of size n, would an algorithm with runtime O(n choose (n/2)) = n!/((n/2)!(n/2)!), a.k.a. an algorithm which evaluates every possible partitioning of the input into two sets of equal size, be considered a polynomial time algorithm?

Comment: Stirling's formula implies $\binom{n}{n/2} \sim \frac{2^n}{\sqrt{n\pi/2}}$, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Both_n_and_k_large).

Comment: ... So no, it is not polynomial time.

Comment: Without Stirling: $\frac{n!}{(n/2)!(n/2)!} = \frac{n}{n/2} \cdot \frac{n - 1}{n/2 - 1} \cdot \ldots \cdot \frac{n/2 + 1}{1} > 2^{n/2}$.